# this.getClass().getResource().openStream("file.xls") returns NullPointerException (MAVEN project)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, filepath

I have a Maven project that I am running tests on, and they wont successfully complete. The issue is that the test returns a NullPointerException when attempting to load a file (which I believe is due to a wrong filepath, but I cannot get it right for some reason).

Here is the location of my test.java file:

C:_MY_PROJECTS\P1\trunk\P1\modules\P1-commons\P1-core\src\test\java\si\smth\P1\test

This is where I keep the resources:

C:_MY_PROJECTS\P1\trunk\P1\modules\P1-commons\P1-core\src\test\resources

Am I missing something here? It used to work on Ant - now that I've re-structured the project for Maven I cannot seem to get it working...

The code:

```
@Test
  public void massImportGDTest_2() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResource("resources/gd_mass.xls").openStream();
    CAopParserMass parser = new CAopParserMass(in);
    CInfo[] result = parser.parse();
    assertEquals(11, result.length);        
  }
```

As the test runs it returns a NullPointerException, I assume cause of a faulty filepath? Any insight on this matter?

Thanks in advance,
Bg

Comment: I don't think you need to prefix with /resources, try this path instead: "/gd_mass.xls". Also you can directly use getResourceAsStream(). In maven you should arrange your directory layout for tests as /src/main/java for source code and /src/test/resources for test resources. [see article](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: `Class.getResource()` returns `null` if the specified resource is not found in the classpath, and if you try to invoke `openStream()` on that then you will certainly get a `NullPointerException`.  That's by far the most likely explanation for your exception.  Whether that's because the path is faulty or because the resource is just unexpectedly missing is something you would need to determine, but it is at least suspicious that the path is a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

I have the document on 
C:\Users\MyProfile\Documents\MyProject\Repo\java-platform\src\main\resources\reports

And this run for me:

```
java.io.InputStream in = this.getClass().getResource("/reports/gd_mass.xls").openStream();
```

Change "/" for "\" and it may not be necessary to indicate "resources" because it starts from there. Try this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResource("/gd_mass.xls").openStream();
```

Comment: Hi Eider and thanks a lot for your help! Sadly, it doesnt change anything however - the exception still occurs at the same spot...

Comment: EDIT: It's actually working, but the test fails due to a different error. Thanks a lot Eider, question answered! Now it's time to debug the new errors. (: